# AWS managed elasticsearch doesn't allow `_render/template` request?

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

When trying to render a query template in AWS managed Easticsearch cluster I am getting an `not allowed` error. however the search by template works fine.

```
GET /_render/template
{
  "source": "{ \"query\": { \"terms\": {{#toJson}}statuses{{/toJson}} }}",
  "params": {
    "statuses" : {
        "status": [ "pending", "published" ]
    }
  }
}
```

return below error:

```
{
  "Message": "Your request: '/_render/template' is not allowed."
}
```

is there a configuration or permission that I need to enable to allow render requests?

Comment: Were you able to get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

AWS managed Elasticsearch/OpenSearch allows customers to only access a set of apis of all supported elasticsearch/opensearch apis.

> is there a configuration or permission that I need to enable to allow render requests?

No, the managed service does not support this.

You can view the list of supported operations here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/supported-operations.html